# Deleting Documents 1 Month later after their creation in MongoDb with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a log collection and would like to remove logs which have been created 1 month ago.

I am using Mongoose in NodeJS and I've  tested with "minute" parameter and it worked. But the problem that I want to be sure that the documents will be deleted one month later.

Here what I did

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/blabla', {useNewUrlParser: true});
mongoose.Promise  = global.Promise;



var Logs = new Schema({

AppName:{
    type: String,
    required: [true,'Application Name field is required']
},  
CreatedDate:{
    type: Date,
    required: [true,'Created Date field is required'],        
},
ExpireAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: '2m' },

});

module.exports.Logs = mongoose.model('logs', Logs);
```

as you can see, "expires" paramter has 2m (2 minutes)
My concern that If I give "1M" (one month), would it accept it? I have not found acceptable paramters.

http://www.albertgao.xyz/2019/02/07/how-to-auto-delete-mongodb-records-after-certain-time-with-mongoose/

I've tried to give direct date + 1month or numeric value as seconds but did not work.

So how can I let delete documents one month later after their creations..

Comment: i guess, it does not mean month for `M`, it again means minute only. instead you can use something like `30d` its not exact although, but for exact 1 month , you might want to calculate the date for 1month after. and  put in in `expireAt ` or  calculate seconds for `expireAfterSeconds `, you can use moment for this date/time operations though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `1m` like as following snippet ,

```
expireAt: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now,
  index: { expires: '5m' },
},
```

5m is a shortcut here, you can refer to this  [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms)  to check how to use words rather than number to make the setup more readable.

Comment: I've tried with "1h" and one hour later the documents have been deleted. But i feel that still its a bit risky for one month. I've used the way that has been given in the other reply, it works. I'll just convert a month as seconds.. Thank you